# Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function

Tags: django, reactjs, redux, django-rest-framework, react-redux

I was trying to develop a login page with the Django rest framework as the backend.  The backend is working perfectly whereas I can't even set up react js.  I am getting an error in the Index.js file of react.  It tells "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component"

[This is what the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyfSh.png)

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Paperbase from './Layout/Paperbase'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './Layout/Login/Login'
import Register from './Layout/Register/Register'


export  function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/dashboard" render={() => <Paperbase /> } />
        <Route path="/account/login" render={() =><Login />} />
        <Route path="/account/register" render={() => <Register />} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

export default App
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import store from './store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { render } from 'react-dom';


ReactDOM.render(
    (<Provider store={store}>
        <App/>
    </Provider>),
     document.getElementById('root') || document.createElement('div') // for testing purposes
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Login.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import LockOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { login } from '../../actions/auth';

const styles = theme => ({

    '@global': {
        body: {
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.white,
        },
    },
    paper: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(25),
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    avatar: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.light,
    },
    form: {
        width: '100%', // Fix IE 11 issue.
        marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
    },
    submit: {
        margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2),
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.light,
    },
});

class SignIn extends React.Component {

  state = {
    email: '',
    password: '',
  };

  static propTypes = {
    login: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool,
  };

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.login(this.state.email, this.state.password);
  };

  onChange = (e) => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });


    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;

        const { email, password } = this.state;
        return (
            <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
                <CssBaseline />
                <div className={classes.paper}>
                    <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
                        <LockOutlinedIcon />
                    </Avatar>
                    <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                        Sign in
                    </Typography>
                    <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                        <TextField
                            variant="outlined"
                            margin="normal"
                            required
                            fullWidth
                            id="email"
                            label="Email Address"
                            name="email"
                            autoComplete="email"
                            autoFocus
                            onChange={this.onChange}
                            value={email}
                        />
                        <TextField
                            variant="outlined"
                            margin="normal"
                            required
                            fullWidth
                            name="password"
                            label="Password"
                            type="password"
                            id="password"
                            autoComplete="current-password"
                            onChange={this.onChange}
                            value={password}
                        />
                        <FormControlLabel
                            control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
                            label="Remember me"
                        />
                        <Button
                            type="submit"
                            fullWidth
                            variant="contained"
                            color="primary"
                            className={classes.submit}
                        >
                            Sign In
                         </Button>
                        <Grid container>

                        </Grid>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
});

export default (withStyles(styles)(SignIn));
```

authreducer.js

```
    import {
    USER_LOADED,
    USER_LOADING,
    AUTH_ERROR,
    LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    LOGIN_FAIL,
    LOGOUT_SUCCESS,
    REGISTER_SUCCESS,
    REGISTER_FAIL,
  } from '../actions/types';

  const initialState = {
    token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
    isAuthenticated: null,
    isLoading: false,
    user: null,
  };

  export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case USER_LOADING:
        return {
          ...state,
          isLoading: true,
        };
      case USER_LOADED:
        return {
          ...state,
          isAuthenticated: true,
          isLoading: false,
          user: action.payload,
        };
      case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      case REGISTER_SUCCESS:
        localStorage.setItem('token', action.payload.token);
        return {
          ...state,
          ...action.payload,
          isAuthenticated: true,
          isLoading: false,
        };
      case AUTH_ERROR:
      case LOGIN_FAIL:
      case LOGOUT_SUCCESS:
      case REGISTER_FAIL:
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
        return {
          ...state,
          token: null,
          user: null,
          isAuthenticated: false,
          isLoading: false,
        };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
```

authactions.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

import {
  USER_LOADED,
  USER_LOADING,
  LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  LOGOUT_SUCCESS,
  REGISTER_SUCCESS,
} from './types';

// CHECK TOKEN & LOAD USER
export const loadUser = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  // User Loading
  dispatch({ type: USER_LOADING });

  axios
    .get('http://localhost:8000/api/auth/user', tokenConfig(getState))
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: USER_LOADED,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
     console.log(err)
    });
};

// LOGIN USER
export const login = (email, password) => (dispatch) => {
  // Headers
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  };

  const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password });

  axios
    .post('http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login', body, config)
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.response.data)
       });
};

// REGISTER USER
export const register = ({ username, password, email }) => (dispatch) => {
  // Headers
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  };

  // Request Body
  const body = JSON.stringify({ username, email, password });

  axios
    .post('http://localhost:8000/api/auth/register', body, config)
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.response.data)
       });
};

// LOGOUT USER
export const logout = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  axios
    .post('http://localhost:8000/api/auth/logout/', null, tokenConfig(getState))
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'CLEAR_LEADS' });
      dispatch({
        type: LOGOUT_SUCCESS,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.response.data)
    });
};

// Setup config with token - helper function
export const tokenConfig = (getState) => {
  // Get token from state
  const token = getState().auth.token;

  // Headers
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  };

  // If token, add to headers config
  if (token) {
    config.headers['Authorization'] = `Token ${token}`;
  }

  return config;
};
```

Comment: What's the react and react-dom version?

Comment: I don't see any hooks used in any of the code you shared, so I suspect it's a react version conflict with one of the import libraries being used.

Comment: react version is 16.13.1

Comment: react-dom version is 16.13.1

Comment: Actually I am getting the type of error only when  I use Provider.  If I remove the Provider, the error goes.

Comment: My react redux version is 7.2.0

Comment: @JoanLouji please, when asking a question on StackOverflow, reduce your code to the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem. While people are here to help, nobody really wants to read through hundreds of (unrelated) lines of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, this error often occurs due to the fact that one of the packages in package.json (often it's `React`) is in `dependencies` (not in `devDependencies`). And this version conflicts with yours.

Comment: Could you perhaps rephrase the answer? I think you're saying that there could be conflicting versions of `React` in `package.json`, which is correct. But it sounds like you're suggesting that `React` should be in `devDependencies`, which is incorrect.

Comment: @Codebling, Yes. You absolutely right: ```React```shouldn't be in ```devDependencies```. But sometimes developers make mistakes :) When developing a package, you might accidentally specify React in devDependencies. When I import this package to myself yours and my version of ```React``` will conflict. That's what I meant